# Tablas multiplicar c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, bucle-for, messagebox

Muy buenas, estoy haciendo un ejercicio en C# pero a través de VS con Windows Forms.
Se trata de pulsar un botón y que a través de MessageBox, te saque las tablas de multiplicar del 1 al 10.
Mi problema es q quiero que cada tabla te la saque en un MessageBox distinto y mi programa lo que hace es añadir las tablas al mismo MessageBox. No sé como hacerlo para que cada tabla sea un MessageBox distinto continuo.

Mi código:

```
string resultado = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("");
            for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++)
            {
                resultado += i + " x " + j + " = " + (j * i) + "\n";                    
            }
            MessageBox.Show(resultado);
```

Comment: mete `string resultado = "";` dentro del primer bucle for. Y quita `MessageBox.Show("");`

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He añadido un titulo. Creo que queda así:

```
string resultado, tabla;

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        resultado = "";
        tabla = "Tabla del "+i + "\n";
        for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++)
        {
            resultado += i + " x " + j + " = " + (j * i) + "\n";                    
        }
        MessageBox.Show(resultado, tabla);
    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado